# Double connection to Tor from one IP

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization

Is there any security issues or deanonymise  techniques when a user use Tor from his tablet and from his Notebook at same moment ? Same question "Is there any security issues or deanonymise  techniques when a Tor user use One Tor browser in his Host machine and other Tor browser in VirtualBox and if user is running one Tor browser in one Virtualbox Machine and other Tor browser in other VirtualBox machine(he have 2 virtualbox machines connecting to Tor) 
I ask that because I know that making Tor to run through 2

Answer (score 1):

No and no.

> Is there any security issues or deanonymise techniques when a user use Tor from his tablet and from his Notebook at same moment?

You use Tor on 2 different machines. They are not connected in any way.

> Is there any security issues or deanonymise techniques when a Tor user use One Tor browser in his Host machine and other Tor browser in VirtualBox and if user is running one Tor browser in one Virtualbox Machine and other Tor browser in other VirtualBox machine(he have 2 virtualbox machines connecting to Tor)

Same. They use absolutely different nodes for their circuits.